# Amazon Simple Product API error when looking up product

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-3.4

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY = "A******************A"
AMAZON_SECRET_KEY = "7***********************E"
AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG = "j*****-20"

amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG, region='US')
print(amazon)
#product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B002RL8FBQ')
```

When I run the code above it works fine and I get this output from the print function:
`<amazon.api.AmazonAPI object at 0x7fb6e59f7b38>`

So everything is working fine with my access key, secret key, and associate tag.

However, if I un-comment the last line `#product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B00EOE0WKQ')` then I get this error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B00EOE0WKQ')
  File "/home/darren/Python_projects/amazon_wp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/amazon/api.py", line 173, in lookup
    response = self.api.ItemLookup(ResponseGroup=ResponseGroup, **kwargs)
  File "/home/darren/Python_projects/amazon_wp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottlenose/api.py", line 251, in __call__
    {'api_url': api_url, 'cache_url': cache_url})
  File "/home/darren/Python_projects/amazon_wp/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/bottlenose/api.py", line 212, in _call_api
    return urllib2.urlopen(api_request, timeout=self.Timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I have followed the instruction from the official github for this https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api and the code I am using you will see I have used from the "Usage" subheading on the github page, thus I am not sure what's going wrong.

For added info, I am using a virtual environment and to show that I have the correct packages installed here is my out put of pip freeze:

```
(myvenv) darren@my_comp:~/Python_projects/amazon_wp$ pip3 freeze
bottlenose==0.6.3
lxml==3.6.0
python-amazon-simple-product-api==2.1.0
python-dateutil==2.5.3
six==1.10.0
```

Also, I have tried several different asin numbers of valid products and I get the same error message.

I am using python 3.4 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: do you have multiple accounts ? did you authorize the account used in the script and not another one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, problem is with region. Please select valid value [from here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html). Explanation can be that AWS can validate your credentials, but when it comes to "real" call it fails, since 'US' is not valid region...

Comment: in my case this work as i in the UK i had to do

    amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG, region="UK")

Answer (score -1):

You might need to authorize your account for [API access](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/registration/pipeline.html). This [step-by-step](http://www.wp-amazon-plugin.com/register-amazon-affiliate-product-advertising-api/) should walk you through it.

**Edit:**

---

I've installed all of the same versions and am using the same python code with my own keys and it works fine.
The only time I encountered that error was when I didn't specify the region (which you are clearly doing).

One thing I'd try is to add the following code into your script:

> import logging
>   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

which should display the following request url:

> DEBUG:bottlenose.api:Amazon URL:
>   http://webservices.amazon.co.uk/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=&AssociateTag=&ItemId=B00EOE0WKQ&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large&S
>        ervice=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=&Version=2013-08-01&Signature=

You can visit this in your browser and should see an XML document returned. If it fails it should hopefully give you a better error than what the pythonlib gives you.

For instance, if I visit https://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/scratchpad/index.html (never got this to work for me) but it provides a list of base URLs for the region.

I created my associate account on the .co.uk region, thus my requests will only be valid for http://webservices.amazon.co.uk, if I instead try to query  http://webservices.amazon.com then I will see:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details.

If you've got an associate account on amazon.com, try it without specifying region as I believe that's default. Apart from the above, check that your VM has internet connectivity and if nothing else works try creating another access key and using that.

Comment: Thanks - I have already gone through that process to get my assoc tag, assoc access api an dsecret key. Maybe I am missing something, but I have previously followed those steps.